# looping through member variables and changing their type (in Python)?

Tags: python, member, self, iterable, mutable

Is it possible to iterate theough some member variables of a defined class, and then change the member variable type?

For instance something like the below:

```
def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    self.A = a
    self.B = b
    self.C = c
    self.memberVarsToChange = {self.A: float, self.B: float}

def convertTypes(self):
    for item, t in self.memberVarsToChange.items():
        item = t(item)
```

The item obviously doesn't refer to the member variable, it's local to the loop. Is there a way to refer to the actual member variable?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you just initializing `self.A = float(a)` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, in Python member variables are called attributes.

You need to store the attribute *names* in `self.memberVarsToChange`, not the attribute *values*. Then you can use `getattr()` and `setattr()` to update the attributes dynamically.

```
def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    self.A = a
    self.B = b
    self.C = c
    self.memberVarsToChange = {"A": float, "B": float}

def convertTypes(self):
    for attr, t in self.memberVarsToChange.items():
        setattr(self, attr, t(getattr(self, attr)))
```