# Will changing the type of a class attribute change the memory location of that class attribute? (Python)

Tags: python, memory, reference, attributes, garbage-collection

I have a class which initially holds an attribute of two types. I later convert one of those types into the other so they are all consistent (following the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558911/looping-through-member-variables-and-changing-their-type-in-python))

So far, when I've been checking the memory locations, the modified attribute is stored in the same place. However, can this be relied upon to be consistent, or is the memory allocation random, and liable to sometimes be in a different place?

Many thanks

Comment: The Python standard makes no guarantees. It depends on the Python implementation and the situation of usage.

Comment: You'll have to show what you're changing. If you're altering a mutable container, the container object may be in the same location, but it really depends on what's being done.

Comment: Python doesn't have a notion of "memory". For all you know, all objects are values stored in an on-disk database, not RAM.

Comment: How are you checking the memory locations? Can you post the code that demonstrates what you're seeing? Why does it matter? Memory locations aren't visible to Python applications.

Comment: I tried, and `id()` says the locations are different: https://ideone.com/PfDmeB